# Adding headers with iTextSharp in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, pdf, header, itext

I'm wondering how can I put a header into my PDF file, cause I've tried the tutorials from here:

http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/tutorial/ch04.html

And it has not worked.

I've done this:

```
Dim head As New HeaderFooter(New Phrase("This is page: "), False)
head.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER
document.Header = head
```

But VS2008 says that `HeaderFooter` is not defined (line 1), and `Footer it's not a member of "iTextSharp.text.document" (line 3).`

I've already included the imports at the beginning of my code and iIdon't have any other problems with the iTextsharps (I mean that it is working apart of the header problem):

```
Imports iTextSharp.text
Imports iTextSharp.text.pdf
Imports System.Data.SQLite
Imports System.IO
```

So please, can anyone explain to me how can i set a header for my pages?

Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to this question depends on which version of the iTextSharp dll you are using.

If you are using a version lower than 5, this should work

```
Imports iTextSharp.text.pdf
Imports iTextSharp.text
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim pdfWrite As PdfWriter
        Dim pdfDoc As New Document()
        Dim pdfMemoryStream As New IO.FileStream("tryme.pdf", IO.FileMode.Create)
        pdfWrite = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, pdfMemoryStream)
        Dim pdfHeader As New HeaderFooter(New Phrase("Im at the head: "), False)
        pdfHeader.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER
        pdfDoc.Header = pdfHeader
        pdfDoc.Open()
        pdfDoc.Add(New Paragraph("Hello World"))
        pdfDoc.NewPage()
        pdfDoc.Add(New Paragraph("Hello World Again"))
        pdfDoc.Close()
    End Sub
End Module
```

**Update**

For version 5+ of iTextSharp the HeaderFooter property has been removed from iTextSharp. To add Headers/Footers now you must use PageEvents. The following code demonstrates how to do this (very simply!)

```
Imports iTextSharp.text.pdf
Imports iTextSharp.text
Imports System.IO
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim pdfDoc As New Document()
        Dim pdfWrite As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, New FileStream("tryme2.pdf", FileMode.Create))
        Dim ev As New itsEvents
        pdfWrite.PageEvent = ev
        pdfDoc.Open()
        pdfDoc.Add(New Paragraph("Hello World"))
        pdfDoc.NewPage()
        pdfDoc.Add(New Paragraph("Hello World Again"))
        pdfDoc.Close()
    End Sub
End Module

Public Class itsEvents
    Inherits PdfPageEventHelper
    Public Overrides Sub OnStartPage(ByVal writer As iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter, ByVal document As iTextSharp.text.Document)
        Dim ch As New Chunk("This is my Stack Overflow Header on page " & writer.PageNumber)
        document.Add(ch)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I think they removed header/footers in v5 as they were restrictive in that you couldn't add much more than basic text chunks to them. Using the OnStartPage event you should be able to add anything you want to the document.

Comment: `Public Class itsEvents Inherits PdfPageEventHelper Public Overrides Sub OnStartPage(ByVal writer As iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter, ByVal document As iTextSharp.text.Document) Dim ch As New Chunk("This is my Stack Overflow Header on page " & writer.PageNumber) document.Add(ch) End Sub End Class ` this method dosn't work, if the pdf have more than 1 page the headers move down and over the body of report.